# Actualizar e incrementar coluna atraves da ordenação (UPDATE e ORDER BY)

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte tabela

```
ID |    NOME     |  ANO  | REGISTO
----------------------------------
0       A          2015      4
1       B          2017      6
2       C          2014      15
3       D          2017      2
4       E          2013      55
5       F          2017      1
6       G          2017      6
7       H          2017      8
```

E fazendo a seguinte query recebo o resultado:

```
SELECT * FROM exemplo WHERE ano = 2017 ORDER BY nome ASC


ID |    NOME     |  ANO  | REGISTO
----------------------------------
1       B          2017      6
3       D          2017      2
5       F          2017      1
6       G          2017      6
7       H          2017      8
```

Pretendo fazer um `UPDATE` que me incremente o valor do `REGISTO` começando por 1 de acordo com a ordenação alfabética. Ou seja:

```
ID |    NOME     |  ANO  | REGISTO
----------------------------------
1       B          2017      1
3       D          2017      2
5       F          2017      3
6       G          2017      4
7       H          2017      5
```

E repetindo o processo pelo anos o resultado final seria:

```
SELECT * FROM EXEMPLO ORDER BY id

ID |    NOME     |  ANO  | REGISTO
----------------------------------
0       A          2015      1
1       B          2017      1
2       C          2014      1
3       D          2017      2
4       E          2013      1
5       F          2017      3
6       G          2017      4
7       H          2017      5
```

Estou questionando o processo apenas através de SQL, sem suporte a linguagens de programação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu caso seria algo mais ou menos dessa maneira, tendo que adaptar as suas reais necessidades.

```
SET @prev := '';

SET @cnt := 1;

UPDATE exemplo e 
       JOIN (SELECT id, nome, IF(@prev <> ano, @cnt := 1, @cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rank, @prev := ano as prev
             FROM   exemplo 
             ORDER  BY ano, nome ASC) e1 
         ON e.id = e1.id 
SET    registo = e1.rank
```

Caso você queria verificar o resultado antes, você pode rodar essa query:

```
SET @prev := '';

SET @cnt := 1;

SELECT id, nome, IF(@prev <> ano, @cnt := 1, @cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rank, @prev := ano
FROM exemplo
ORDER BY ano, nome ASC
```